# Difference between $A+B$ and $A \cup B$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Basic set theory: $A$ and $B$ are two sets. I assume that $A+B$ isn't the same as $A\cup B$. I know what $A\cup B$ is but what is $A+B$?

The context: I need to show that if A and B are open, then A+B is open. And I don't know how to tackle this problem. Mainly because I wasn't sure about the A+B in the first place. Anyway, feel free to suggest how to prove what I mentioned above.

Comment: You should make clearer what the context is.

Comment: It could be $A+B:=A\cup B$, where $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Sometimes $A + B$ is "disjoint union", eg $A + B \triangleq \{\text{inl } a \mid a \in A\} \cup  \{\text{inr } b \mid b \in B\}$ or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to do a sum-up and give my own thinking.

As suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1555032/135592), in the case of vector spaces $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$. That is, $A+B$ is the set of all sums of two vectors, one in $A$ and one in $B$. If $A,B$ are open, then let $a+b\in A+B$. I can find $V_A\subseteq A,V_B\subseteq B$ such that they are open and contain $a$ and $b$ respectively. In particular, I can find a ball, if we are considering a normed space. Then I only need a ball around $a$, since if that ball is $V$ then $V+b$ is a ball around $a+b$, showing openness. For generic topological vector spaces, you can still say that $b+A$ is open for all $b\in B$, so $A+B=\bigcup_{b\in B}(b+A)$ is a union of open sets, ergo it is open.

But the notation is used for different purposes, it seems. Indeed, [someone](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1555042/135592) suggests it might be a synonym for disjoint union, i.e. $+$ might be used as $\dot\cup$ or $\sqcup$. In that case you have a union of two open sets, which is open by definition of topology.

If you have two subspaces $V_1,V_2$ of a space $V$, as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1555044/135592), and $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ (seems a necessary hypothesis to conclude), then $A+B$ can be viewed as $A\times B$, so if you have the product topology on $V_1\oplus V_2$ (which is the same as $V_1\times V_2$ more or less), then you have $A+B$ is open as it is a product of open sets. If $V=V_1\oplus V_2\oplus\textit{something else}$, then you product won't be open, since it lies in a subspace. Well, it won't be open in the product topology, but if you make the space discrete, for example, then anything is open.

To conclude, I quote the last answer I haven't referred to yet:

> Context is important, and notations differ between different authors. ++ for union is not very common these days, but you will find it in some older books and papers. An example I just happened to pull off my shelf is Natanson, "Theory of Functions of a Real Variable".

Answer (score 4):

Usually $A+B$ means $\{a+b\,:\,a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Context is important, and notations differ between different authors.  $+$ for union is not very common these days, but you will find it in some older books and papers.  An example I just happened to pull off my shelf is Natanson, "Theory of Functions of a Real Variable".

Answer (score 0):

If they are sets without any structure (so no addition operation on elements) then it could mean disjoint union, i.e., a synonym for U but only to be used when it has already been established that the sets have no elements in common.

Answer (score 0):

When $A$ and $B$ are vector subspace, there is a nice illustrative example: Let
$$ A =\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\} \qquad \text{and}\qquad B=\{(0,y)\mid y\in\Bbb R\}.$$
Geometric interpretation: $A$ is the set of points on the the "x-axis" and $B$ is the set of points on the "y-axis" in the plane.
Then 
$$ A\cup B =\{(x,y)\mid x =0 \text{ or } y =0\} \qquad \text{and}\qquad A+B = \{(x,y)=(x,0)+(0,y)\mid x,y\in \Bbb R\}=\Bbb R^2.$$
Geometric interpretation: $A\cup B$ is the set of points on one of the axis and $A+B$ is the whole plane.